# create a UITableViewController programmatically in Swift

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8, programmatically-created

I'm trying to, as the title say, set up a UITableViewController programmatically. After a few hours of trying I hope someone can help me. And, yes, I hve checked out other posts on this matter:

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UITableViewController {

    init(style: UITableViewStyle) {
        super.init(style: style)
        // Custom initialization
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // #pragma mark - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView?) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell? {
        var cell = tableView?.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as? UITableViewCell

        if !cell {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }
        cell!.textLabel.text = "test"
        return cell
    }

}
```

and the appDelegate looks like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

        let mainViewController: UITableViewController = MainViewController(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
        let navigationController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController()
        navigationController.pushViewController(mainViewController, animated: false)

        self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
        self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
```

The program run, but as soon as it does, I get the following error:

```
fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(nibName:bundle:)' for class 'HelloWorld.MainViewController'
```

I then changes the `MainViewController(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)` to `MainViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)` but then I get the following syntax error: `Extra argument 'bundle' in call`

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: How are you defining the MainViewController class?

Comment: What's the definition for MainViewController? Are you inheriting directly from UITableViewController? Do you define any initialisers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using a subclass of UITableViewController with no issues, using the (nibName:bundle:) form, but I've overridden that in my subclass. I tried replacing my subclass with a standard UITableViewController, and it still worked fine. Are you possibly overriding an init(...) method in your subclass?

Comment: When I removed the init function in MainViewController the program run just fine. I just came over a post here on SO with the same problem (don't know how I didn't see that post before posting..). But why is this necessary?

Comment: make sure you're calling the appropriate inherited init(...) method from your own initializer.

Comment: Swift makes inherited initializers inaccessible for clients of your derived class when you add a designated initializer. It looks similar to private inheritance in C++ where the inherited methods/data are implicitly moved to the "private" class section. The reason is simple: if there is a custom initializer then your class probably requires this initializer to construct class "invariant".
But there is a bug: if you create class derived from UITableViewController and add custom initializer that calls super.init(style:) it will fail with _use of unimplemented initializer 'init(nibName:bundle:)'_

Answer (score 3):

In the AppDelegate or wherever you call the TableViewController:

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    if let window = window {
      window.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
      var mainTableViewController = MainTableTableViewController(style: .Plain)
      window.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainTableViewController)
      window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    return true
}
```

In the UITableViewController (assuming no custom TableViewCell implementation):

```
import UIKit

class MainTableTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  override init(style: UITableViewStyle){
    super.init(style: style)
  }

  override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!){
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

  }

  // MARK: - Tableview Data Source

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return [*YOUR_DATA_ARRAY].count
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel!.text = [*YOUR_DATA_ARRAY][indexPath.row]
  }
```

For an full example: visit: https://github.com/ericcgu/EGStormTracker

Answer (score 0):

I just removing

```
init(style: UITableViewStyle) {
    super.init(style: style)
}
```

and then init like this:

```
 let mainViewController: UITableViewController = MainViewController()
```