# Swift unit test not recognizing new class initializer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I changed the initializer signature on a Swift class. My other swift classes recognized the change, but my unit test class is giving me an error when I update the method call

```
Extra argument 'bundle' in call
```

Here is my new initializer signature:

```
var vc = ListController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil, contractor: theContractor)
```

The old one was:

```
var vc = ListController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil, contractor: theContractor, estimate: theEstimate)
```

Things I have tried:

1. Cleaned project
2. Removed and re-added the ListController and the test class from compile sources for both the unit test target and the test target
3. Removed project's derived data
4. Have completely re-written the test class from scratch just to put it under a new file name

The bottom line as of right now is that my test class is not recognizing the initializer signature change.

ListController is written in Swift as well as the test class.

Even the autocomplete puts in the correct method signature. But if you do CMD+Space on the method signature it says "Symbol Not Found".

Comment: "Extra argument 'whatever' in call" seems to be one of those Swift error messages that often means that something completely different is wrong. As a sanity check, does the rest of your code compile if you comment this line out?

Comment: Yes it does compile. And the new changes work fine in the build target - just not with the unit tests

Comment: And `theContractor` is definitely of exactly the correct type? (I've seen that cause this problem, too.)

Comment: Often this indicates parameters being passed are of the wrong type, or you are passing an optional when a non-optional is required (or vice versa).

Comment: @MikeTaverne i know what you are saying. But I assure you they are the correct types. I only deleted the last parameter. That was it. Also - even the autocomplete fills out the appropriate signature- just still throws this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Sergiy Salyuk [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098779/create-a-uitableviewcontroller-programmatically-in-swift):

> Swift makes inherited initializers inaccessible for clients of your
>   derived class when you add a designated initializer. It looks similar
>   to private inheritance in C++ where the inherited methods/data are
>   implicitly moved to the "private" class section. The reason is simple:
>   if there is a custom initializer then your class probably requires
>   this initializer to construct class "invariant". But there is a bug:
>   if you create class derived from UITableViewController and add custom
>   initializer that calls super.init(style:) it will fail with use of
>   unimplemented initializer 'init(nibName:bundle:)'

Sounds like you've encountered essentially the same issue?